# Use method of custom object class in Apache Velocity template

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I pass to Apache Velocity template a variable of type `User` (created by me). `User` has method `getUsername()` and in Velocity template I use this as follows:

```
#if($user)
<p>
User Created $user.getUsername()
</p>
#end
```

but output is `User Created $user.getUsername()` and not `User Created Pluto` as expected; Why?? Can You help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that the value returned by the getUsername() method is null, or perhaps that that method doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right, in a certain sense my was a retorical question, but only with this answer I noticed the real problem, thank you!